# How to Rotate Image based on Velovity + GestureListener

Tags: animation

I m rotating Image in "onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, final float velocityX, final float velocityY) " method using RotateAnimation.Here I am using an fix angle to rotate image , pls suggest me how can I rotate angle based on velocity pls.

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had referred something like this.. Nice link but you have to make lot of changes with respect to make it perfect rotate animation logic. Here is the [dialer animation link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer/)